# Tabs should not be on the newest tab where remove one in Blazor

Tags: c#, css, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm having a problem with Blazor...

I'm a beginner in frontend development and I would like my tab page to reselect the user object that matches the SelectedUserId after calling the delete method...Currently, the component is not re-rendered and the active state is not reassigned after deletion.I must be doing something wrong.  Can someone help me take a look at the problem...thanks

```
@page "/user-tab"

<h3>User Tab</h3>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @foreach (var user in Users)
    {
        <li class="nav-item" style="position: relative;">
            <a class="nav-link @(SelectedUserId == user.Id ? "active" : "")" @onclick="() => SelectUser(user.Id)">
                <span>@user.Name</span>
                @if (SelectedUserId == user.Id)
                {
                    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" style="font-size: 0.5rem; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px; background-color: transparent; border: none;" @onclick="() => RemoveUser(user.Id)">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" style="line-height: 1;">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                }
            </a>
        </li>
    }
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" @onclick="AddUser">+</a>
    </li>
</ul>

@if (SelectedUser != null)
{
    <br />
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active">
            <h4>@SelectedUser.Name</h4>
            <sapn>@SelectedUser.Remark</sapn>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }

    private List<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>
    {
        new User { Id = 1, Name = "User 1", Remark = "This is user 1." },
        new User { Id = 2, Name = "User 2", Remark = "This is user 2." },
        new User { Id = 3, Name = "User 3", Remark = "This is user 3." }
    };
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        SelectedUserId =  Users.Any() ? Users.Min(user => user.Id) : 0; ;

    }

    private int SelectedUserId { get; set; }

    private User SelectedUser => Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == SelectedUserId);


    private void SelectUser(int userId)
    {
        SelectedUserId = userId;
        StateHasChanged(); 
    }

    private void AddUser()
    {
        int newId = Users.Count > 0 ? Users.Max(u => u.Id) + 1 : 1;
        Users.Add(new User { Id = newId, Name = "New User " + newId, Remark = "New Remark" });
        SelectedUserId = newId;
    }

    private void RemoveUser(int userId)
    {
        var userToRemove = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);
        if (userToRemove != null)
        {
            Users.Remove(userToRemove);
            var nextSelectedUserId = Users.Any() ? Users.Max(user => user.Id) : 0;
            SelectUser(nextSelectedUserId);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I don't have much knowledge about front-end development...

Comment: I try your code, If i delete User2, the selected user now is the next(user3), what do you mean about `reselect the user object that matches the SelectedUserId after calling the delete method`? could you explain it? thank you so much.

Comment: when I delete User2  I lose selected  tab .But I want one of the remaining tabs to be selected...

Comment: Still can't get your point, When i delete user2, user3 tab will be selected.

Comment: Did you use the 'x' in the top-right corner of the tab to delete it...After deletion, I lost focus, meaning the selected tab is not preserved.so..

Comment: yes, after i click 'x', It focus on the next tab, it seems work fine in my case.